# Pass variables from project to playbooks ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

This is my setup. I have created a scm type git project and have my code there. My playbook is on that repository as well and it contains docker build and run command. In order to build my docker I should execute my build command where my docker file is located (in this case where ansible project clones /var/lib/awx/project). I want to get that path to my ansible playbook.

My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name : build docker
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      command : docker build -t "test-api" .
    - name: run docker
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      command : docker run -it -p 80:9001 --name api test-api
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the variable to the playbook when you execute the `ansible-playbook` command. This is what you could do:

> ```
>  ansible-playbook my-playbook.yml -e"path='/var/lib/awx/project'"
> ```

Then just use it in the playbook as a normal variable: `{{ path }}`

This is useful if you decide to change the path. If you have any question about this, feel free to ask in the comments

Comment: im using ansible tower, can i use the same?

Comment: I don't know Ansible Tower, but I think it might be the same. [Go to this website for some examples](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/tower_cli.html#specify-extra-variables). I think the option "--extra-vars" is the same as the "-e" I used

Comment: yes, i used extra variables to map with playbook. it void me defining them in the playbook. great way.

Comment: @DasunHettiarachchi if you have a big amount of variables, you can define them in a file. This is a good solution if you work with big variables or encrypted Ansible passwords

Comment: yes i'm working with lot of vars, can you encrypt vars and store in a file and will ansible able to decrepit and use?

Comment: Yes you can. You can encrypt individual variables or even the hole file. All this done with [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/vault.html#what-can-be-encrypted-with-vault). Also, if you save variables in a file (it must be in YAML syntax), you can include that file with `-e"@filename.yml"`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `vars` for defining the variables:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    file_path: "<your file path>" 

  tasks:
    - name : build docker
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      command : docker build -t "test-api" .
    - name: run docker
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      command : docker run -it -p 80:9001 --name api test-api
```

And In your command access that variable like "{{ file_path }}"

Comment: @Dasun Hettiarachchi: Please let me know if you need more information ?

Comment: yes. so i have to define the path in order to achieve this? is there any way i can get the path from ansbile variable without define it?
for example it clone to path like this  var/lib/awx/projects/_16__docker
i have to check on the server every time i add a project

Comment: In order to access the ansible variable you need to define either in playbook file. or if you use `roles` then under `vars`->`main.yaml`.

Comment: You can define the clone path in a variable and use that variable for cloning step and also build command

Comment: okay. im not familiar with roles. il test with variables in playbook

Comment: @here i have different question, when i run update on scm on project 
i ran into error saying Fatal: Failed to resolve 'origin/04753df8240a4a186e6f0f6e177319fec1c3d242' as a valid revision.

Comment: This is something related to error while `cloning` of your project